# Why is unpickling a custom class with a restricted Unpickler forbidden although it is allowed in find_class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm required to run some code repeatedly to train a model. I found that using pickle for saving my object after one iteration of the code was useful, and I could load it and use it in my second iteration.

But as pickle has the security issue, I wanted to use the [restricted_loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#restricting-globals) option. However I can't seem to get it working for custom classes. Here's a smaller block of code where I get the same error:

```py
import builtins
import io
import os
import pickle

safe_builtins = {
    'range',
    'complex',
    'set',
    'frozenset',
    'slice',
}

allow_classes = {
    '__main__.Shape'
}

class RestrictedUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        # Only allow safe classes from builtins.
        if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins | allow_classes:
            return getattr(builtins, name)
        # Forbid everything else.
        raise pickle.UnpicklingError("global '%s.%s' is forbidden" %
                                     (module, name))

def restricted_loads(s):
    """Helper function analogous to pickle.loads()."""
    return RestrictedUnpickler(io.BytesIO(s)).load()

class Person:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        age: int,
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Shape:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: Person,
        n: int = 50,
    ):
        self.person = Person(
            name = name,
            age = "10",
        )
        self.n = n
        
s = Shape(
    name = "name1",
    n = 30,
)

filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "temp.pkl")
with open(filepath, 'wb') as outp:
    pickle.dump(s, outp, -1)
    
with open(filepath, 'rb') as inp:
    x = restricted_loads(inp.read())
```

Error:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 63
     60     pickle.dump(s, outp, -1)
     62 with open(filepath, 'rb') as inp:
---> 63     x = restricted_loads(inp.read())

Cell In[20], line 30, in restricted_loads(s)
     28 def restricted_loads(s):
     29     """Helper function analogous to pickle.loads()."""
---> 30     return RestrictedUnpickler(io.BytesIO(s)).load()

Cell In[20], line 25, in RestrictedUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
     23     return getattr(builtins, name)
     24 # Forbid everything else.
---> 25 raise pickle.UnpicklingError("global '%s.%s' is forbidden" %
     26                              (module, name))

UnpicklingError: global '__main__.Shape' is forbidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only allowed classes which come from the module `builtins`.

But `__main__.Shape` is a class with the name `Shape` in the module `__main__`, not a class with the name `__main__.Shape` in the module `builtins`.

So an obvious fix would be to change

```
if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins | allow_classes:
    return getattr(builtins, name)
```

to

```
if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins:
    return getattr(builtins, name)
elif module == "__main__" and name == "Shape":
    return Shape
```

Comment: That was useful! I started importing all my custom classes and even library ones like numpy, but don't think I can actually do this as I got stuck with these errors: `_pickle.UnpicklingError: global 'numpy.random._pickle.__randomstate_ctor' is forbidden`
`AttributeError: module 'numpy.random._pickle' has no attribute '_RestrictedUnpickler__randomstate_ctor'`